# Why is my bun js application not working on production server

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, bun, hono

Here is what app.tsx looks like (entrypoint of application):

```
import { Hono } from "hono";
import { serveStatic } from "hono/bun";
import path from "path";

import Articles from "./views/Articles.tsx";
import ArticlePage from "./views/components/ArticlePage.tsx";
import { GetRelatedArticleLinks } from "./utils/functions.ts";
import Projects from "./views/Projects.tsx";

const app = new Hono();

app.use("/*", serveStatic({ root: "./public" }));

app.get("/", async (c) => {
  const homepage = Bun.file(path.join(process.cwd(), "views", "index.html"));
  return c.html(homepage.text());
});

app.get("/articles", async (c) => {
  const articles = Bun.file(path.join(process.cwd(), "articles_data.json"));

  return c.html(<Articles articles={await articles.json()} />);
});

app.get("/articles/:article_title", async (c) => {
  const articleTitle = c.req.param("article_title");
  const articleContent = Bun.file(
    path.join(process.cwd(), "article_content", `${articleTitle}.html`)
  );
  const articlesHeaders = Bun.file(
    path.join(
      process.cwd(),
      "article_content",
      "head_metadata",
      `${articleTitle}.html`
    )
  );

  const relatedArticles = await GetRelatedArticleLinks(articleTitle);

  return c.html(
    <ArticlePage
      content={await articleContent.text()}
      head={await articlesHeaders.text()}
      relatedArticles={relatedArticles}
    />
  );
});

app.get("/projects", (c) => {
  return c.html(<Projects />);
});

Bun.serve({
  fetch: app.fetch,
  port: 8080,
});
```

I am using bun js as the runtime (v 1.0.25). Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM oven/bun:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN bun install

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["bun", "run", "app.tsx"]
```

When building out this image and running locally this works perfectly fine, but when attempting to run on digital ocean and AWS the Docker container wont start? Why is this happening? The only log I get is:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error
```

Comment: Are you developing and building on a newer ARM-based Mac?  If you try to run an ARM-based image on an x86-based host, you'll get this error.